# Mv files with number formatted in 2 digits

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to mass rename files from:

"02 Disc 01 My Song.mp3"

to

"Disc 01 My Song 02.mp3"

How can I do this in bash? Please note that all numbers are formatted in two digits (1-9 is prefixed with a zero)

List of files:

```
01 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
02 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
03 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
04 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
05 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
06 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
07 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
08 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
09 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
```

Comment: Is `Disc` going to stay the same and not contain a whitespace? Can you provide a full list of files you want to rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use Perl implementation of `rename` program (there is
another program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux`
package). Example - first let's re-create a list of files you
presented in your question:

```
$ touch 0{1..9}\ Disc\ 01\ My\ Song.mp3
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 01 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 02 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 03 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 04 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 05 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 06 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 07 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 08 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:41 09 Disc 01 My Song.mp3
```

Run `rename` and list files again::

```
$ rename 's,([0-9]+) Disc 01 My Song.mp3,Disc 01 My song $1.mp3,' *
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 01.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 02.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 03.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 04.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 05.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 06.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 07.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 08.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 30 01:42 Disc 01 My song 09.mp3
```

Comment: More generally: `rename 's/^(\d+) \s+ (.+) (\.[^.]+)/$2 $1$3/x' *`

Comment: To check if your rename is the perl one: `file "$(type -p rename)"` and the output contains "Perl script text"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for f in *.mp3; do 
  foo=$(echo "${f%.*} ${f%%[^0-9]*}.mp3")
  mv "$f" "${foo#[0-9]* }"
done
```

Which results in:

```
'Disc 01 My Song 01.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 02.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 03.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 04.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 05.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 06.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 07.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 08.mp3'
'Disc 01 My Song 09.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution. Using the `-a` flag from the builtin `read` and Command Substitution and a here string.

```
for f in *.mp3; do
  renamed=$(
    read -ra var <<< "$f"
    printf '%s' "${var[1]} ${var[2]} ${var[3]} ${var[4]%.*} ${var[0]/%/.${var[4]##*.}}"
  )
  echo mv -v -- "$f" "$renamed"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the result.

Comment: This assumes each filename contains the same number of words.